# how to convert react form into React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, graphql-js

I'm quite new to the React Native although done some stuff in ReactJS.

Is there any way to convert this code below to be fully React Native? Currently it works on web browser but there are problems on iphone's Expo GO app due to button, input and form tags.

```
function PostMessage() {
  let input;
  const [postMessage, { data }] = useMutation(POST_MESSAGE);

return (
    <View
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        alignItems: "center",
        marginTop: "1em",
      }}
    >
      <form
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          postMessage({ variables: { messageBody: input.value } });
          input.value = "";
        }}
        style={{ alignItems: "center" }}
      >
        <input
          ref={(node) => {
            input = node;
          }}
          style={{ width: 500, height: 30 }}
        />
        <button type="submit" style={{ height: 36 }}>
          <Text>Send</Text>
        </button>
      </form>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: React can't be directly converted into React native, because they are two different things. DOM Elements like `form` and `input` are not supported in react native. `input` becomes `TextInput` and `button` becomes `Button` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately React cannot be fully converted to react native, because your React code you are using DOM elements that do not exist in React Native. If you want to transcribe your code to react native, it would look like this:

...
...

```
return (
 <View style={{...}}>
    <TextInput onChangeText={...} />
    <Button Title="Send" onPress={...}>
</View>
)
```

**What I changed**

1. I removed the component Form 
   Unfortunately React Native does not support a Form component (but if you want, you can use a library like tcomb-form-native), so I removed it to get your code back up and running.
2. Replaces the Input component that is only present in the DOM with TextInput 
   React Native does not have Input, but TextInput you just made a mistake in the syntax.
3. I added the title property to the button 
   If you want to put a text inside a button, it is not necessary to add a component for that, just use the text property

**Additional comments**

To be able to redeem the value present in your TextInput, you must use some Hook (the same ones you used in ReactJs, for more information read the ReactNative / ReactJs documents), and thus use the data in any way you want.

I hope I was helpfull!